# Understanding homeomorphisms: Intuition vs formalism

Tags: general-topology

Before formally learning topology I know that two objects are consider the same topological object if you can continuously deform one into another without tearing or gluing peaces together.

Now that I'm actually studying topology I learned the concept of homeomorphisms and immediately the following question appeared:

> We know that $[-1,0]\cong [-2,-1]$ and that $(0,1]\cong (1,2]$. Now let $f$ be an homeomorphism between $[-1,0]$ and $[-2,-1]$ and let $g$ be an homeomorphism between $(0,1]$ and $(1,2]$.
>
> Now let's define the following funcion:
> $$k:[-1,1]\to [-2,-1]\cup (1,2]$$
> Defined as:
> $$k(x)= \Bigg\{ \begin{matrix} 
> f(x) & \text{if }x\in [-1,0] \\
> g(x) & \text{if }x\in (0,1]
>  \end{matrix}$$
>
> Then we would have that $[-1,1]\cong [-2,-1]\cup (1,2]$.

Is this correct? Because we are deforming the interval $[-1,1]$ in a way that "tears" the interval and leaves a "hole", meaning that they should not be topologically the same. But on the other hand I don't see any problem with my argument

---

Edit:
I'll try to prove that $k$ is continuous.

Let A be an open subset in $[-2,-1]\cup (1,2]$. Let $\mathcal B'$ be the basis for the subspace $[-2,-1]\cup (1,2]$. Then we have that $A$ is the union of some elements of $\mathcal B'$:

$$A = \bigcup_{i\in I}B_i$$

For some index set $I$ and for $B_i \in \mathcal B'$.

Now we have:

$$k^{-1}(A)=\bigcup_{i\in I}k^{-1}(B_i)$$.

We can divide the different $B_i$'s by whether they belong in $[-2,-1]$ or $(1,2]$:

$$\bigcup_{i\in I}k^{-1}(B_i)=\bigcup_{i\in I}f^{-1}(B_i \cap [-2,-1])\cup \bigcup_{i\in I}g^{-1}(B_i \cap (1,2])$$

As $f$ and $g$ are homeomorphisms, we have that $f^{-1}(B_i \cap [-2,-1])$ and $g^{-1}(B_i \cap (1,2])$ are open sets in [-1,0] and (0,1] respectively. Meaning that their union is an open set in [-1,1]. Thus proving that $k$ is continuous.

Comment: I don't see any reason for $k(x)$ to be continuous

Comment: You can of course define such a function but it may not even be continuous; let alone a homeomorphism

Comment: Why is this not continuous? @alphaomega

Comment: Why do you think that it should be continuous?

Comment: I did not say it's not  (even though it's true if you are considering the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$, since continuous image of a connected set is itself a connected set). I said that the way you defined $k$ cannot guarantee continuity

Comment: "I know that two objects are consider the same topological object if you can continuously deform...". This is the sort of intuition that one needs to unlearn when you start learning topology.

Comment: So That intuition is not always correct? When should I take advantage of that intuition? @AnginaSeng

Comment: And in this case, is that intuition correct or not? @AnginaSeng

Comment: Does that mean that the function $k$ is indeed an homeomorphism, but the way that I defined it, It does not follow trivially that it's continuous and it still needs to be proved? @alphaomega

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães Firstly, the way you defined it is not enough to deduce that $k$ is continuous. Secondly, it cannot be continuous in any way. The reason is what I describe inside the parenthesis above. Lastly, your proof of continuity id wrong. For example $(-\frac{1}{2}, 0]$ is an open set in $[-1,0]$ but not in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Besides, if your proof was correct, every piecwise function, where every "piece" is continuous, would be continuous as well, which is obviously not true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you're using the Euclidean topology.

This is not correct, as you can tell with most of the point-set topology invariants such as connectedness or compactness.

Your function clearly jumps at $0$ and hence is not continuous.

Comment: Check my edit. I made a proof. I'm not sure it is correct so I would appreciate if you spot some mistake you'd point it out

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães Consider the inverse image of the open set $[-2,-1]\subseteq [-2,-1]\cup(1,2].$ This pulls back to $[-1,0],$ which is not open in $[-1,1].$ The issue with your proof is that the union of an open set in $[-1,0]$ and an open set in $(0,1]$ need not be open in $[-1,1].$ $[-1,0]$ is a concrete example of this. More generally, if $X$ is a topological space and $Y\subseteq X$ is a subspace, an set $U$ which is open in $Y$ need not be open in $X$ (it's the intersection of an open in $X$ with $Y$).

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães I have not read your attempt but trust that Stahl wrote out the mistake. As I have mentioned in the beginning, any such attempt is wrong since each of these invariants proves that the spaces are not homeomorphic.

Comment: "closedness" is not an incariant of  a topological space, though. compactness and connectedness are.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma By closedness I mean that for $A \cong B$ where $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ with the Euclidean topology, then $A$ is closed iff $B$ is closed. (And otherwise, it would still be an invariant since the entire space is always closed. It's just a useless invariant.)

Comment: @QiZhu in the reals $[0, \infty) \cong [0,1)$ while one is closed and the other not. So not an invariant.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Ok, you are right, of course. Thank you for the comment. I naively thought that it would also be true for closed sets since it is true for open sets.

Comment: @QiZhu openness is nontrivial ( invariance of domain ). But a homeomorphism of subsets need not extend to the whole space so closed being complementary to open does not help. Being closed in a Euclidean space does imply a topological invariant: topologically complete and being a Baire space being obvious ones.